# Is there any advantage using UserDetailsService of Spring Security, when setting membership with JWT?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-filter

I'm applying JWT to authenticate the requests. Parsing and Validating works in my Spring Cloud Gateway.
I made a custom filter on `SecurityWebFilterChain`, which parse and validate the JWT in request header.

I will add this custom filter to ServerHttpSecurity using `ServerHttpSecurity.addFilterBefore(myCustomJwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)`.

I want to use
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)` of Spring Security to authenticate the request.

I found that most of examples of it use UserDetails to make Authentication class.

Most of examples I found use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, and I found that it requires `UserDetails`. To build `UserDetails`, it essentially requires username, password, roles.

But in my case, I do not want to validate my jwt with User DB every time I got requests. Also, I do not need the password of user since I will not validate it once I generated Token. I want to use only Username and Roles in JWT payload itself.

In summary, I want to make `Authentication` class only with username and roles and set it authenticated if parsed jwt is validated with my custom method.

It works well with custom userDetails:

```
UserDetails userDetails = User.builder().username(String.valueOf(parsedInfo.get("username")))
    .authorities(parsedInfo.get("roles")).password("dummypassword").build();
```

But I have to set Dummy password into it, which I do not need.

I think my solution is not properly applying spring security.
But if I won't use UserDetails, is there benefit to use spring security?

Is there any better solution for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to validate the JWT token then you can use Spring AOP for that.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class JwtAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.yourpackageName.* (..))")
    public void checkJwtToken(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        String jwtTOken = request.getToken();
        if (null == jwtToken) {
            throw new Exception("Token Not Found. ");
        }
        parseToken(jwtToken);
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }

}
```

If you get the token, parse it and also check the expiry. If above everything works fine, you can proceed your `JoinPoint`.

Comment: It's my pleasure.